# Difference between Component-Scan and @Component ?

Tags: spring, annotations

I'm bit confused about these annotations, since I am very new to Spring. 
I tried to get it on google and found many answers but still, I did not got the clarity. I got to know that @Component is Super annotation for @Repository, @Service and @Controller, but I'm still in doubt when to use @Component and when to Use @ComponentScan Could any one help me to get clear understanding of these both annotations, and what is difference in both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the annotation @ComponentScan , you can tell Spring where do your Spring-managed components lie. These Spring-Managed components could be annotated with @Repository,@Service, @Controller and ofcourse @Component.

For example - Lets say your spring-managed components lie inside 2 packages com.example.test1 and com.example.test2. Then your componentScan would be something like this

```
                @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example.test1","com.example.test2")
```

OfCourse the annotation ComponentScan has a lot of other elements.

You can read more about them here -
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html.

On the other hand, @Component is a generic annotation for any Spring-Managed component. For example - If you create a class called Testing inside the package com.example.test1 and annotate with Spring @Component.

```
             @Component    
             Class Testing    
     {

             public Testing()
            {
            }

            public void doSomething()
           {
            System.out.println("do something");
           }

    }
```

Following the above example, During Component Scan it will be picked up and added to the application context.

Hope this makes things clear :)

Comment: so can be use @ComponentScan alone or we should use it along with some other annotations like @Service?

Comment: Are u following any guide?

Comment: I got complete clarity now. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

To put it in plain terms,
@ComponentScan scans all the class files specified under the base package i.e. search for the files under this package for any annoted java files with @Component, @Repository, @Service and @Controller and if it finds any of them it will register it into the bean factory.

It was a pain to write everything in an XML file, where you have to specify what each class was, if it was a Service or a Controller, so Annotation came into the picture to avoid this...Internally it does the same thing like as if you had  written a xml file which mentioned what was what

Comment: does ComponentScan also finds Bean annotated classes ?

Comment: Yes it does that job too...

Answer (score 0):

**@Component** is a generic annotation for any Spring-managed class/component.

```
@Component
class YourBusinessClass {
    Dependency1 dependency1;
    Dependency2 dependency2;
    ............
}
```

Whereas **@Component-Scan** annotation is used to scan the packages for any annotated java class/file (@Component, @Service, @Repository, etc).

@Component-scan also takes package name as an argument. If we don't specify it, by default it scans the current package.

```
@ComponentScan("com.user.package.config1")
public class BusinessApplication {
...............
}
```