# What's the use of @ComponentScan annotation if all the beans can be annotated with @Component?

Tags: spring

Why do we need to write @Component annotations and then again write @ComponentScan in Spring? We can define @ComponentScan with a special package , but I'can imagine a scenario when we annotate a class as a @Component and then exclude it from search.

Comment: Specifying a package allows avoiding to scan every other package. Remember that the classpath has your code, but also all the libraries it uses. Why scan 100,000 classes when you know only 200 are relevant?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Component-Scan and @Component ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558563/difference-between-component-scan-and-component)

Comment: But isn't there a way to distinguish libraries and main app from code without specifying a package?

Answer (score 2):

In simple words `@Component` is used to mark a class as bean that are need to identified during `@componentscan`,

And  `@componentScan` only look for the beans that are annotated with `@Component` and create beans for them.

Usually `@ComponentScan` will scan all classes and sub packages classes, but if you have any classes in other packages that are not sub packages of main package, then you should manually add them in `@ComponentScan`

If you look at documentation all `@Controller` , `@Service` are annotated with `@Component`

```
@Component
public @interface Controller {
…
}
@Component
public @interface Controller {
…
}
```